# Difference between ANCOVA and Randomized Block ANOVA

Tags: ancova

What is the difference between an ANCOVA and a Randomized Block ANOVA?

Answer (score 2):

ANCOVAs have both continuous and categorical predictors. ANOVAs just use categorical predictors.

A randomised block ANOVA includes experimental blocking. When you use experimnetal blocking, you divide subjects into subgroups (i.e. blocks), such that the variability within blocks is less than the variability between blocks. Then, subjects within each block are randomly assigned to treatment conditions. Compared to a completely randomized design, this design reduces variability within treatment conditions and potential confounding, producing a better estimate of treatment effects.